# What does 「耳元を過ぎる」 mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, phrases

Source: 「[スピーチ・バルーン](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a001134/l0118e8.html)」by 大滝詠一

> 想い出のブラス・バンドが
> 耳元を過ぎる

The Brass Band of memories
Passes by close to the ears (playing)

Would that be an accurate translation of 耳元を過ぎる?

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this 過ぎる means "to pass by", and 耳元を過ぎる is a literary, poetic way of saying "to hear (for a short time)", or sometimes "(for the sound) to cease to be heard".